# display edit button only if the logged in user is same as the user's page?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**example:**

1.example.com/username1

2.example.com/username2

i want to take to user to the edit profile page, i got all the permission working correctly and set the views accordingly.

**My Problem:**

i loggedin as username1 so i should not be able to access `example.com/username2/edit/`. i got this to work in the views by adding some permissions, but i dont want to display the edit button when the loggedin username1 views the page of username2. Now i use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` and this results in display the edit button on page of username2 even though the loggedin user is username1.

Any simple solutions that can be used in the templates directly?

Answer (score 1):

views.py

```
class CanEditMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        The method populates Context with can_edit var
        """
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(CanEditMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #Update Context with the can_edit
        #Your logic goes here (something like that)
        if self.request.user.slug == self.kwargs['slug']:
            context['can_edit']=True
        else:
            context['can_edit']=False
        return context
```

`class ProfileView(CanEditMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    .....`

template.html

```
{% if can_edit %}
    <a href="#">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if `request.user` is the same as the user that the URL is assigned to. In your request you have a key called 'user' which is your logged one (if logged) or anonymous (if not logged).

`{% if user.is_authenticated %}` is for checking if the [user is authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) (as the name says), that means if the user is a valid user (for example he clicked the link in the email).

Comment: can you give a solution? i tried `{% if user==self.user %}` its not possible to use `==` operators in the template. Is there any other way?

Comment: I would rather do this in the view or a seperate templatetag. You can write an ``assignment_tag()`` which takes the context. In your context you have the URL and the ``request.user``. Simply get the user who is assigned to the URL (in your case im guessing that the 'username2' is a URL named group so you can do something like: User.objects.get(username=username2) and check if its PK it is equal to request.user.pk. If so, just return True, else False. Then you can just do {% if check_my_user %} and put the edit button in the if statement

Comment: No problem, please just marked the answer as correct :)